# Autocomplete search with barcode scanner

Tags: javascript, php, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, barcode-scanner

I have implemented an autocomplete search, where the user writes the product name and the name will be suggested, and by clicking on the name, it will add it's information to existing table.

But for a barcode scanner, where the product name will be automatically put into the input box, when it scans the product. But the autocomplete doesn't suggest anything.

How to continue with a suggestion, when barcode scanner scans the product? 
Here is the code I have used for the autocomplete search.

View:

```
<div class="form-group m-form__group">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Search by product name or barcode
       </label>
  <input type="text" autofocus class="form-control m-input" id="productSearch" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Product name">
</div>
```

JavasSript part:

```
$('#productSearch').autocomplete({
  source: '{!! asset('productSearch') !!}',
  select:function(suggestion,ui) {    
    var markup = "<tr id="+ui.item.id+"><input type='hidden' name='product_id[]'  value="+ui.item.id+"><td><i class='flaticon-delete-1 delete-row' onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td><td>"+ui.item.value+"</td><td>"+ui.item.unit_price+"</td><td><input type='text' name='quantity[]' class='quantity' value='1'></td><td class='total'>"+ui.item.unit_price+"</td><td>"+ui.item.notes+"</td> </tr>";              
    $("table tbody").append(markup);          
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a barcode won't fire any key events so you could do something like:

```
$('#my_field').on({
    keypress: function() { typed_into = true; },
    change: function() {
        if (typed_into) {
            alert('type');
            typed_into = false; //reset type listener
        } else {
            alert('not type');
        }
    }
});
```

Depending on when you want to evaluate this, you may want to do this check not on change but on submit, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete is triggered on *keydown* event, so you can trigger it if value of your input is not empty (it's updated by barcode scanner):

```
if (!$('#productSearch').val()){
    $('#productSearch').trigger('keydown');
}
```

Comment: Can you suggest with code please? 
I'm not getting it how i implement with existing code

Comment: @User57 Updated answer try adding this to your JavaScript. Maybe there's a better way, but you need to provide more code. How do you put data in input when  it's read by a barcode scanner?